# History of Wagtail admin

Tags: wagtail

Is there any way to view the history of changes made in the Wagtail admin? I can see the five most recents edits, but the history complete, is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you dig into wagtail model admin ? http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/
You could list all pages and sort theme by publishing date

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
    from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import PageRevision
    #get all revisions order by date
    PageRevision.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')

    #get revision specific page(ex:4)
    PageRevision.objects.filter(page_id=4).order_by('-created-at')
```

It solved my problem, you can paginate the results too with Paginator.